# c++ cannot convert 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} to 'int' in assignment

Tags: c++

Trying to find log base 2 of a number in c++ but am stuck on this error.

cannot convert 'std::basic_ostream::__ostream_type' {aka 'std::basic_ostream'} to 'int' in assignment

```
int main()
{
    int n, result;
    cout << " enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    result = (n >= 0) ? cout << log(n)/log(2) : cout << "Invalid";
    cout << "Log base 2 of " << n << " is " << result;
    cout << endl;
    
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            
}
```

Comment: What's wrong using a  if statement instead??

Comment: You try to assign the result of an output operation (`cout << …`) to an integer variable. That is exactly what the error is telling you

Comment: Also, try using godbolt.org and trying with different compilers (gcc/clang/msvc) when you have an error. Some compilers produce better diagnostics than others.

Answer (score 0):

cout does not have return value.
cout << has return value, but it is not int.
cout << return value is a reference to count, which enables us link variables like court << a << b << ... .

Comment: Consider rewriting this so it is clearer, has fewer spelling errors (you use 3 different names for `cout`) and uses some formatting for code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).